# How to configure simple routing between NICs

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I have the following setup:

Physical router

- Internet interface 192.168.1.1
- Port forwarding of IP 1194/udp to virtual machine below

Virtual machine (VM)

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 Server AMD64
- One virtual NIC that bridges (shares transparently) my host's physical NIC
- Static lease (192.168.1.58) assigned by physical router
- OpenVPN installed and configured; virtual interface tun0 with IP 10.8.0.1 (followed guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Successful:

- My laptop can connect and get an IP 10.8.0.x
- My laptop can ping internal devices

Not successful:

- Internal devices cannot ping 10.8.0.x
- They cannot even ping 10.8.0.1 which is the tun0 interface

So routing is working from 10.8.0.x > 10.8.0.1 > 192.168.1.58 > 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.x ... but routing is NOT working the opposite direction!

I added a route in my physical router (using DD-WRT v24-sp2):

- Destination LAN NET: 10.8.0.0
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.58
- Interface: LAN & WLAN

But routing is still not working to the 10.8.0.0 network. I suspect the issue lies with my Ubuntu server that is running OpenVPN. I suspect the issue is that while the article above gave a step to setup routing from 10.8.0.0 to the internal network, it didn't include a step from the internal network to 10.8.0.0. So maybe I just need to add a rule that facilitates this? I'm thinking in iptables, but I also use UFW; so I don't know how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, messed around for hours and hours until I found Pritunl (https://github.com/pritunl/pritunl), it uses OpenVPN but takes care of all the iptables headache that is needed for the routing you want and gives you a nice web GUI to manage clients, etc.

Not the answer you might be looking for, but for me it was a pragmatic solution, balancing the desire to "figure it out" and the desire to just have a working VPN solution ;-)